# Can we reverse a stack in O(1) time

Tags: c++, stack, reverse

I have to reverse a stack in O(1) or constant time. Its a usual "array" based stack class with push, pop and top methods; in which additional public method of reversal has to be added. The reversal method has to work inconstant time to achieve reversal. Can queues be used to achieve this goal  as question hints at using circular arrays to achieve this goal? Its an assignment question..  Any tip?

Comment: If you can access the elements out of LIFO order, it's more than a stack. What exactly can you do with your stack? The standard one doesn't let you go out of order, which you've already done with the swap solution.

Comment: How is the stack represented? If you could get down to the representation, you could start pulling from the other end. If all you have is `top()` and `pop()`, then obviously it takes `N` calls to `pop()` to get to the bottom-most element - there's no way to obtain it in `O(1)`.

Comment: Its a usual stack class with push, pop and top methods; in which additional public method of reversal has to be added. The reversal method has to work inconstant time to achieve reversal. Can queues be used to achieve this goal? Its an assignment question.

Comment: Be aware that "O(n/2)" is usually written more simply as "O(n)" since constant factors are irrelevant to big-O notation.

Comment: @JaMiT Not just 'usually'. Correctly. *O(N/2)* is *wrong,*

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I'm trying to be diplomatic. Sometimes a nudge in the right direction works better than a shove. ;)

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate your help, just edited my question to put all details

Answer (score 0):

You can design a stack that is reversible in constant time, but there are many stacks out there that require O(N) time to reverse. For example, if each node in a stack contains just data plus a pointer to the next (toward the bottom) element, then a stack with `N` nodes has `N` pointers to change, as the "next" relation is changing for every node.

When all of the `N` nodes need to change, the process is (at least) O(N).

*To get a stack reversible in constant time, you could use a doubly-linked list and keep track of which direction is currently down. With this setup, you reverse the stack by flipping the "which direction is down" flag. Be aware that this approach adds overhead to most other stack operations, since the flag needs to be checked every time you need to find a "next" node, such as when pushing or popping.*

Comment: It has to be an array based stack and the question hints at using circular arrays to get O(1), concept that is used in array based queues

Comment: @Libra2019 That information is not in the question, so it is irrelevant to answers to the question. Also, it would be rude to add information to the question if that information would invalidate an existing answer. Maybe you want to work on writing better, more detailed questions? *(If you have a better version of your question, you could try asking it in a new question. Be sure to emphasize that you are adding requirements so people are less inclined to close it as a duplicate of this one.)*

Comment: @Libra2019 Then again, the last paragraph of my answer is probably adaptable to your situation. You might want to give that a try before re-asking.

Comment: thanks and I apologize. Im new at this forum. Ill try to write a better question.

Comment: @Libra2019 No worries. The way I see it, you're the one most inconvenienced by this slip. So if you can learn from it, then something good came from it.